# C++ COM\DCOM version management

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, com, dcom

This is may be very old problem but i really fustrating with same due to some API issues.

I am using some Desktop application API who's version changes each and every month with new feature.
Lets consider following scenario,
A Company ABC LTD introduce one window application ABCPRO now when they introduce it they dont have com support that is in version 1.0.0.0 the ABCPRO dont have com API.
Now company progress and introduce new version of ABCPRO 1.0.0.1 , even this version they dont have com support.After some beta releases of ABCPRO in 1.* they finally introduce com suport for ABCPRO in version 2.0.0.0.

now its pleasure for us to get ABCPRO API and do some functionality.things works great with version 2.0.0.0.

Now in version 2.0.0.1 they introduce one more feature say LMN and which userful to us.so we remove ABCPRO 2.0.0.0 and install ABCPRO 2.0.0.1.Things work great for all our 2.0.0.1 customers but it fails when our customer have ABCPRO 2.0.0.0 So my executable crash on machine where ABCPRO 2.0.0.0 is present because i develop executable using 2.0.0.1.

So how to come out of this problem of versioning because i known in feature there are lots of versions of ABCPRO are going to be introduced with the feature that we needed but what about all old versions?????

Following code may clear you.

```
int main()
{
   IABCPROAPI ABCPRO;
   VARIANT var;
   ABCPRO->GetNameOfServer(&Var);
   VARIANT LMNVar;
   ABCPRO->GetLMN(&LMNVar);             //This introduce in version 2.0.0.1
}
```

**EDIT:-**

How to know version of executable in c++??

Or try catch may be useful??

Comment: if(ABCPRO->GetVersion() >= 2.0.0.1) ABCPRO->GetLMN(&LMNVar)

Comment: @JoãoAugusto thanks for reply but i already think on that point, but they dont have function that return me version of API.

Comment: @JoãoAugusto may be some try catch type of solution can be helpful.

Comment: You link to a DLL ? If so you can probably use GetProcAddress to check if "GetLMN" exists.

Comment: @JoãoAugusto i am not linking to DLL. i am directly importing executable as below , #import "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ABCPRO\\ABCPROSvc.exe" raw_interfaces_only

Comment: Try catch of thing may useful..

Comment: Then why don't you check the target ABCPRO version, and according to that you install a version of your software.

Comment: @JoãoAugusto yup I known getting version from registry but i search each and every key of registry we donsnt find it in resistry even it in install program as well as in uninstall program..:(

Comment: If you manage to get access to the target .exe you can probably extract a version from it and use it.

Comment: @JoãoAugusto how to do that??

Comment: If you change a COM interface (number of methods, order of methods, binary signature of methods), you must create a new interface with a new GUID, for example IABCPROAPI2 with the new members. You can make it derive from IABCPROAPI or not.

Comment: @SimonMourier i agree but ABC LTD not creating new interface they updating interface with same name.:(

Comment: Well, they should be out the COM business if they really do this. This is a very basic COM rule. There's not many thing you can do on your side.

Comment: Simon is right.  The programmer for ABC clearly doesn't understand the kind of problems he's causing.  The odds you'll find him here are zero.  Pick up the phone and tell him about it.

Comment: @SimonMourier reality is that they doesnt bother about we using this guys com companant as they gient company they are not listing our criteria.

Comment: @HansPassant i dont think so they even pick our phone to listen!!!

Comment: If they don't offer a useful service to you, don't use them. Complaining during all your life about how bad company ABC is doesn't sound like a very effective strategy.

Comment: @DanielDaranas thanks for reply but as i said "this guys are software gient they doesnt bother about we are using this guys com companant".

Comment: @Sankaganak and as I said, "If they don't offer a useful service to you, don't use them." They are a company, not a dictatorship ruling your country.

Comment: Your best bet is the File Version suggestion. Can you find the EXE or DLL that implements IABCPROAPI on your disk?  Right-click it and select Properties.  If you are lucky, there will be a Details tab that contains a File Version, e.g. 2.0.0.1 that actually changes with their releases.  You can then read this info with `GetFileVersionInfo`.

Comment: Another way is to compute a MD5 or SHA hash of each version of the EXE or DLL and compare it to the found version at runtime; then you will know by the hash which version it is.

Comment: @DanielDaranas I believe the service is useful, but the packaging is not.  What is not a very effective strategy is telling one's management to not use a 3rd party library because of inconvenient packaging.